# Now that I completed the StarCraft II Campaign, can I play the Lost Viking arcade without restarting?

Tags: starcraft-2

I've finished the StarCraft II campaign, and now when I select the campaign I have a list of the missions instead of the ship (or of Char). Can I play the Lost Viking game from there, or do I have to start another campaign?

Comment: does that still work? loading the game and then playing lost viking?

Comment: @Volkanİlbeyli couldn't tell you, it's been two years.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should be able to play the Lost Viking game by loading up any of your saved games from the campaign that you already played.  Even if you didn't save any yourself, the game autosaves at the end of each mission, so just load one of those.

Comment: Well that's kind of antagonistic... having to load back to the Ship in order to play? Lame!

Thanks for your answer.

Comment: My autosaves don't go past when I was on Char. :/

Comment: Looks like you get to go back and re-play the intro missions! Go for 100% achievements :).

Comment: All previous saves are stored in your Starcraft folder, I just had to bring up an older one.